# username and login through mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, email, authentication

I have a username/database that i wanna log into via PHP in the back end - so i created 2 files - one called login.php and the latter called process.php -

here's the code for them both -

login.php:

```
 <form action="process.php" method="POST">
    username: <input type="text" name="username"/></br>
    password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

process.php:

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','semen1985*','forum');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE (Email='$username' AND password='$password')'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password ';
}
if(!$result){
    echo 'Query Failed ';
}
if ($result==1){
    echo 'Correct Password!!!';
} else {

echo "Wrong Username and/or Password!";
}

?>
```

Anyways, I seem to be continuously getting the following result - ***Query Failed Wrong Username and/or Password!***

This is even after i attempt multiple correct entries for email/username (same thing) and password...does anyone of u know what the problem is or how i could fix this simple code up?

Comment: What's in your database. Also, use PHP's PDO classes.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Comment: As David is probably saying. Please use hashing for passwords. Even if it's a quick app, it's best practice.

Comment: Are your credential correct? Replace the connect line with this:  `mysqli_connect('localhost','root','semen1985*','forum') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));`. What's the result?

Comment: Hashing is just one thing. NEVER create SQL query directly from an input parameter.

Comment: @user3047348 regardless of the need for sql security. To focus on your problem. Look at my previous comment. Can you connect to the db?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. And you should use md5 hashes at least.

Answer (score 4):

Your query is wrong

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE (Email='$username' AND password='$password')'";
```

This query has an extra single quote at the end of the string that is causing the problem.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE (Email='$username' AND password='$password')";
```

Keep in mind that this is an insecure way of creating queries.  You should look into using parameters for your query.  I'm not familiar enough with mysqli to give you an example, , but with PDO you would do something like this:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Email=:username AND password=:password");
$sth->bindParam(":username",$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(":password",$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','semen1985*','forum');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE Email='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password ';
}
if(!$result){
    echo 'Query Failed ';
}
if (count($result)==1){
    echo 'Correct Password!!!';
} else {

echo "Wrong Username and/or Password!";
}

?>
```

Comment: Try this. If you have errors again, do a var_dump($result) and show the result of the var_dump